# How to replace spectator shaders with shaders that have a texture using a resource pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

**TL;DR**: I want to turn [this](https://i.postimg.cc/sDcRtY6C/2022-08-20-15-39-38.png) into [this](https://i.postimg.cc/t4M8j2Fw/2022-08-20-15-41-14.png) by replacing shaders with a resource pack.

I already know how to replace the existing spectator shaders using a resource pack. I know they have a vertex shader, a fragment shader (both use GLSL), and the [render program](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shaders#Render_program) apparently (the .json files that somehow use OpenGL) in the ["program" folder](https://i.postimg.cc/ZqJcQGJK/shaders.png). There's also the [render pipeline](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shaders#Render_pipeline) in the "post" folder. For example, "spider.json" has "rotscale" for the vertex shader and "spiderclip" for the fragment shader. There's another "spider.json" in the "post" folder. That means rotscale.vsh and spiderclip.fsh are used. But, I'm trying to replace the program shaders with shaders that have a texture for scopes for a minigame I'm making with Spigot plugins (that's besides the point).

So, I need to somehow make a shader that all it does is display that [texture](https://i.postimg.cc/V6MrqFhQ/image.png) like if you used stb_image (if you know a little OpenGL, like I do). That way, when I set the shader as the creeper shader in my plugin, for example, the player will just have the replaced shader. It would just make them have like a battle rifle scope overlay.

Does anyone think they know how a shader like this could be made in Minecraft? Do I need to learn more about normal OpenGL shaders and shader programs before I continue, or is the way the render program and pipeline work only for Minecraft?